# Local database not refreshing after updating data from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, sql-server-ce, local-database

I'm working with a local database, and it works well, the whole app. The problem is that I'm facing with some annoying things. If I update, or add new data to my local database, I have to close the whole app and start it again so I can see the new data I have entered. Why is it not refreshing and how can I solve it?

Here is how I add data:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                label5.Text = "1";
            }
            else
            {
                label5.Text = "0";
            }

            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                label5.Text = "2";
            }

            if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Fara";
            }

            if (textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                textBox2.Text = "0";
            }

            if (textBox3.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                textBox3.Text = "0";
            }

            if (numeTextBox.TextLength != 0 && prenumeTextBox.TextLength != 0)
            {
                var connString = (@"Data Source=" + Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + @"\Angajati.sdf");

                //var connString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Stellwag\Stellwag\Angajati.sdf";

                using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //deschide conectiunea in db
                        conn.Open();
                        //creaza comanda in SQL Server CE
                        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
                        //conecteaza cmd la conn
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        //adauga parametru pt campul poza cu value image
                        SqlCeParameter picture = new SqlCeParameter("@Poza", SqlDbType.Image);
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
                        byte[] a = ms.GetBuffer();
                        ms.Close();
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Poza", a);
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO info(Nume, Prenume, Data, Proiect, Schimburi, Poza, Acord, Baza) VALUES('" + numeTextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + prenumeTextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "', '" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "', " + label5.Text + " , @Poza, " + textBox2.Text + ", " + textBox3.Text + ");";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        conn.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("Salvat cu succes!");
                        textBox1.Clear();
                        textBox2.Clear();
                        textBox3.Clear();
                        numeTextBox.Clear();
                        prenumeTextBox.Clear();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Trebuie sa completezi campurile inainte de a salva!");
            }
}
```

Here is how I update it:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            //var connString = (@"Data Source= |DataDirectory|\Angajati.sdf");
            var connString = (@"Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + @"\Angajati.sdf");

            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
                    //conecteaza cmd la conn
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    //adauga parametru pt campul poza cu value image
                    SqlCeParameter picture = new SqlCeParameter("@Poza", SqlDbType.Image);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
                    byte[] a = ms.GetBuffer();
                    ms.Close();
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Poza", a);
                    var query = "UPDATE info SET Nume='" + textBox5.Text + "' , Prenume='" + textBox4.Text + "' , Data='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "', Proiect='" + textBox1.Text + "', Schimburi='" + label10.Text + "', Poza=@Poza, Acord='" + textBox2.Text + "', Baza='" + textBox3.Text + "'  WHERE Nume='" + textBox5.Text + "' AND Prenume='" + textBox4.Text + "'";
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Salvat cu succes!");
                    this.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            } 
}
```

Here is how I search data:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (textBox1.Text.Length != 0)
            {

                var numePrenume = textBox1.Text.Trim().Split(' ');


                    if (numePrenume.Count() > 1)
                    {
                        var nume = numePrenume[0];
                        var prenume = numePrenume[1];
                        var connString = (@"Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + @"\Angajati.sdf");

                        using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                conn.Open();
                                var query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info WHERE Nume='" + nume + "' AND Prenume='" + prenume + "'";
                                var command = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);
                                var dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
                                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                                //checks if there's the searched record is in the db.
                                int infoCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

                                if (infoCount > 0)
                                {
                                    Info form = new Info(nume, prenume);
                                    form.Show();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Nu exista un angajat cu acest nume");
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Nu ai introdus prenumele");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Nu ai introdus nici un nume!");
                }
}
```

Comment: where is your code that load data?

Comment: Load data where? I add data in a separate form. I close it, I try to search the name previously added, and doesn't work. If I close the app and reopen it, it works. If I load data in the form where I have to search it won't work either, because form is not loading again after I close the form where I add the data. I have load data but for other forms.

Comment: @Ezekiel if "form is not loading again after I close the form where I add the data" how does it know about new data?

Comment: @Ezekiel add your search code then?maybe we can help

Comment: @codroipo I know what you are telling. But that's actually the fact .. how can I update the data, I mean, refresh it, so I can use the new data when I press that button which actually adds the data. So, to make it clear.. I press the button which inserts data in db, but the same time, after insert, it should refresh the data, so I can use it without loading the form again.

Comment: How do you display data on app startup? should be right after InitializeComponent();

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: When app starts, in the main form it is selected when search button is clicked. onLoad() it only binds data to a gridview used to export data to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by changing the path to the db, it was something wrong at it, and by creating a refresh function for my gridView called after the insert. Bellow is the code for the solution:

**Getting the path like this now:**

```
string startPath = Application.StartupPath;
var filepath = startPath + "\\" + "Grupe.sdf";
var connString = (@"Data Source=" + filepath +"");
```

**The refresh function:**

```
public void refresh()
        {
            var connString = (@"Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + @"\Grupe.sdf");
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var query = "SELECT * FROM copii";
                    var command = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);
                    var dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
                    var dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
```